# I believe I've found a third and fourth group of degree four. Tell me how wrong I am.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

According to every source I could find, the Cyclic group Z4 and the Klein four-group are the only two groups of degree 4.  As I'm new to group theory, I decided to figure out the groups by myself by creating multiplication tables through simple logical steps.  It was a trivial process for degrees 1,2,and 3, but when I got to degree 4 I found "new groups".  I've been trying to figure out where I went wrong, so I'm going to give you the multiplication tables of my "new groups" and hope that someone will tell me why they're not actually groups.  (I also found a couple groups of degree 5, and from what I know, there is a rule about groups of prime degree that say that I should be wrong, but I don't know why the extra ones that I found aren't groups either.  I'm hoping that these responses will help clear that up for me.)

---

$$\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4\\
2&1&4&3\\
3&4&2&1\\
4&3&1&2\end{matrix}$$

and:

$$\begin{matrix}1&2&3&4\\
2&4&1&3\\
3&1&4&2\\
4&3&2&1\end{matrix}$$

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call your first group $G = \{e,a,b,c\}$, and your second group $H = \{1,x,y,z\}$.

Note that $b^2 = a$, so we may re-write $G = \{e,b^2,b,c\}$. Next, note $b^3 = b^2b = ab = c$, so we have $G = \{e,b^2,b,b^3\} = \{e,b,b^2,b^3\}$ making it clear that $b$ generates $G$.

This suggests the map $\Bbb Z_4 \to G$:

$0 \mapsto e\\1 \mapsto b\\2 \mapsto b^2 = a\\3 \mapsto b^3 = c$

and to verify this is an isomorphism, you need only verify:

$k + m(\text{ mod }4) \mapsto b^{k+m(\text{ mod }4)} = b^kb^m$ for $k, m \in \{0,1,2,3\}$

A similar analysis holds with $H$ using $x$ as a generator.

You're correct in some sense in that your groups are indeed distinct *products* on a set of four elements, but "re-naming" the elements leads to the same *kind* of group structure (cyclic) which is what the notion of isomorphism is meant to capture (the same in all important algebraic ways, but not necessarily *identical* sets).

Answer (score 1):

They are both isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_4$.  The key is to find the element of order $2$, so the correspondence is $$\begin {array}{c|c|c} \Bbb Z_4 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline 0 &1&1\\1&3&3\\2&2&4\\3&4&2\end {array}$$  As $\Bbb Z_4$ is isomorphic under the interchange $1 \leftrightarrow 3$ you can make that swap here if you want.